# Sails.js attribute type array in waterline mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I want to create a model like below. users model having attribute agreements  of type array.I was not able to find a example in waterline where attributes type is an array of object. Please advise 
`

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    userName: {
      type: "string",
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: "string",
      required: true,
      minLength: 2
    },
    phone: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: "string",
      minLength: 6

    },
    roles: {
      type: "array",
      required: true,
      enum: ['Admin', 'User']

    },
    agreements: {
       type : "array",
      agreement :{
        version : "string",
        dateSigned :"date",


      }

    },
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Use one to many association.

Assume that your model is `Model.js`

```
agreements: { collection: 'Agreement', via : 'model' }
```

Create `Agreement.js` in `models`

```
module.exports: {
  attributes: {
    model      : { model: 'Model' },
    version    : { type: 'string' },
    dateSigned : { type: 'datetime' }
  }
}
```

See this [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many).

Comment: Its many to many relationship. Users must sign all agreements. and apart from agreement model i need to store some extra  fields which are specific to particular user and agreement. Like (dateSigned , IP address and User agent of client machine) .

Comment: You could create a model (maybe named `UserAgreement` or `AgreementSignature`) that has a OneToMany relation to `User`, a OneToMany relation to `Agreement` and the attributes that you want.

Comment: It's true, all that you need is fixing your database structure and associations, because `agreement : { version : "string", dateSigned :"date" }` is not a valid configuration.